# Rails respond to restful input via html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

We have a Rails app where we are adding Workorders via the Restful interface.

This is the controller code:

```
# POST /workorders
# POST /workorders.json
def create
  @workorder = Workorder.new(params[:workorder])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @workorder.save
      format.html { redirect_to @workorder, notice: 'Workorder was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @workorder, status: :created, location: @workorder }
  else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @workorder.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

When the workorder is added, the response is coming from this line of code:

```
format.html { redirect_to @workorder, notice: 'Workorder was successfully created.' }
```

What the other app gets in return is:

```
<html><body>You are being <a href="http://ndeavor.ameipro.com/workorders/50">redirected</a>.</body></html>
```

50 is the new workorder.id, but we are having trouble parsing that.

Is there a way to put the workorder.id into the header of what's returned?  We need the app thats sending the data to know what the new workorder.id is.

Also, is there a way to know that the request is coming from the other application instead of a new workorder created in the Rails ui.

Thanks for your help!!

UPDATE 1

Please clarify something about REST for me.  If the restful input is json, then the controller responds back with json?  If the input is html, can the controller respond with json or only html?

When I'm testing using RestClient, is there someway to turn this url into json input or add something that asks for a json response?

```
http://localhost:5000/types?type[id]=318&type[typecode]=test4
```

Comment: What is your "other app" doing?  What is it coded in, what's the use case?

Comment: We are using Mule to move data from an asset management system to our new Rails application.  For some testing we are using Wiztools Restclient.

Answer (score 0):

`response.headers['ETag'] = @workorder.id` might work.

But a better way would be to send over json and have your client parse that, instead of trying to scrape data out of HTML.

Looking at the [documentation](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation-3.2/display/MULE2USER/Using+the+Mule+Client#UsingtheMuleClient-AssociatingPropertieswiththeMessage) for Mule, it looks like you should be able to set the accept header like this:

```
props.put("Accept", "application/json");
```

To which the rails app will respond with the `format.json` block.

Alternatively, you can just make it always respond with json by taking the `render :json` call out of the `respond_to` block:

```
def create
  @workorder = Workorder.new(params[:workorder])
  if @workorder.save
    render json: @workorder, status: :created, location: @workorder
  else
    render json: @workorder.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

Comment: How do I send over json?  The client application is sending html as input to create the new workorder.  Is it possible to have html input, but a json response?

Comment: I got > wrong number of arguments (3 for 2) for line  `format.html { redirect_to @workorder, response.headers['ETag'] = @workorder.id, notice: 'Workorder was successfully created.' }`

Comment: I changed the controller to `        format.html { redirect_to @type, response.headers['ETag'] = @type.id }` .  I get the ETag in the response header.  But, it's value is ETag: "fbedd2e864b1fd43c6ec4da7b51e0e47"